# Debug an instantly failing/never appearing child process

Tags: process, background-process, clone

I have an executable binary (it's a device driver).
It runs and instantly exits with a successful 0 return code.
On one computer it creates the all important child process I can see with pgrep, but sadly not on my other computer.
The output running it with `strace` ends:

```
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f2851597310) = 32167
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

But there's no process (32167 in this case) to be found on that computer.

I don't know how to work out what's going wrong.
Nothing pops up for the child with `sudo execsnoop -x` running.
The source code isn't available.
(Not the main objective but it'd be great if it didn't clone but just ran everything in the foreground.)
It's this file if it helps: https://github.com/elmadjian/tobii_4C_for_linux/blob/main/tobii_usb_service/usr/local/sbin/tobiiusbserviced

EDIT: End of `strace -f command` output:

```
23747 clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f789577f310) = 23748
23747 exit_group(0)                     = ?
23748 umask(000)                        = 022
23748 setsid( <unfinished ...>
23747 +++ exited with 0 +++
23748 <... setsid resumed>)             = 23748
23748 brk(NULL)                         = 0x21bd000
23748 brk(0x21de000)                    = 0x21de000
23748 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/var/run/tobiiusb/tobiiusbservice.pid", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
23748 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/localtime", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
23748 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3648, ...}) = 0
23748 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3648, ...}) = 0
23748 read(3, "TZif2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\7\0\0\0\7\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 3648
23748 lseek(3, -2321, SEEK_CUR)         = 1327
23748 read(3, "TZif2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\7\0\0\0\7\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 2321
23748 close(3)                          = 0
23748 socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC, 0) = 3
23748 connect(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/dev/log"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
23748 close(3)                          = 0
23748 exit_group(1)                     = ?
23748 +++ exited with 1 +++
```

Comment: Please strace using `strace -fF command`.

Comment: Thank you I didn't know about that. I just did -f not -fF, my man page says -F is deprecated.

Comment: I don't know how old your system is but yeah newer straces don't need -F.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/dev/log"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

It wants to write to the system log, it's missing. Something is wrong with your system, this file `/dev/log` normally should exist.

Comment: Yeah you're right /dev/log is not there. I'll investigate. I'm on Void Linux (my init is runit).

Comment: It was actually the pid file but you got me there.